# In dual basis, why the functions are of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

My book says (Linear Algebra - Lipschutz): Let V vector space where $dim(V) = n$. Any functional $\phi$ of $V*$ has the representation $\phi(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + ... + a_nx_n$. **Why?**

I also need to study the topic "Dual basis" in Linear Algebra. **What books would you recommend?** I am reading Kenneth Hoffman. Thanks in advice.

Comment: seek for  the  Riesz's Representation Theorem

Comment: What exactly is your question about dual bases?  You say something in the title, but it's not clear exactly what you're asking.  What do you mean by *"functions are of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i$?"* Is your question something like *"why is the dual basis a basis?"*?

Comment: Also, for the record: even if you do have the necessary amount of reputation, making new tags should be avoided.  The point of tags is to group your question with similar questions.  If the tag doesn't exist, then making the new tag won't group your question with any others in particular.

Comment: I've edited now. Thanks for the info, Omnomnomnom. Too thanks  janmarqz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a vector space and $X^*$ be the dual space. Then $X^*$ consists of linear functions $T:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a basis of $X$. Define $a_i:=T(e_i)$. Any vector  $x\in X$ can be written as $x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i$. Thus by linearity $T(v)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i$.